# Why does the user IDs listed not match the number of users who like a Facebook Post?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

After getting an access token, I made a request to FB's Graph API for post information from a Facebook page. The number of likes do not match the FB's IDs listed. For example, it may say there are 4 likes for a particular POST, but it only provides me 1 or 2 user information. Why is that? Is there a way to get all the user ID information?

Comment: It is highly likely that some users do not want their account information broadcasted, so they "privatize" it using their account settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your access token owner is blocked by a user, you might see that. Or there might be some other of their privacy settings preventing you from seeing them.